# codeception test in CircleCI Error: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, phpunit, yii2, codeception, circleci

I have a problem. I've run automatic test in CircleCI, but the test results were fail. Then I debug with SSH. The results were success when I run same test command in terminal.

**command:**

```
$ cd tests; codecept run && cd - || exit 1 returned exit code 1
```

**Automatic test results:**

```
Time: 9.93 seconds, Memory: 32.75Mb

OK (24 tests, 52 assertions)
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'var_export does not handle circular references' in /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Subscriber/ErrorHandler.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Codeception\Subscriber\ErrorHandler->errorHandler(2, 'var_export does...', '/home/ubuntu/id...', 187, Array)
#1 /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseVarDumper.php(187): var_export(Object(Pheanstalk\Exception\ConnectionException), true)
#2 /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseVarDumper.php(147): yii\helpers\BaseVarDumper::exportInternal(Object(Pheanstalk\Exception\ConnectionException), 0)
#3 /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Target.php(241): yii\helpers\BaseVarDumper::export(Object(Pheanstalk\Exception\ConnectionException))
#4 [internal function]: yii\log\Target->formatMessage(Array)
#5 /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/FileTarget.php(106): array_map(Array, Array)
#6 /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/log/Tar in /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Subscriber/ErrorHandler.php on line 49

PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1046740958 bytes) in /home/ubuntu/idarex/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseVarDumper.php on line 187 cd tests; codecept run && cd - || exit 1 returned exit code 1
```

debug with SSH results:

```
Tests\codeception\mobile.unit Tests (0) -----
---------------------------------------------


[tests\codeception\mobile]: tests from /home/ubuntu/idarex/tests//codeception/mobile

Time: 7.22 seconds, Memory: 31.50Mb

OK (24 tests, 52 assertions)
```

I have tried to set memory_limit in dependencies.

```
$ echo "memory_limit = 2048M" > ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv global)/etc/conf.d/memory.ini
```

but the results were fail as well.

Comment: you do know most severs have separate php.ini file for command line,  right?  Not saying that is the problem but, well if works in the command line and not the server might be something to look at.

Comment: Well I'd start with removing that var_export output too, that recursion will be ... um ... a good place to store all your ram.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the Automatic test also use command line in CircleCI.

Comment: did you remove the var export, do you understand what that error means, it means the var export has a circular reference, it's somewhat like outputting an infinite loop.  It means you probably have a class that references a 2nd class that references the first class. They reference each other, I think var_dump may do better then var_export

Comment: I don't understand why the codeception error with var_export. And I have tried to use the command, `cd tests; codecept --no-interaction --no-colors --silent --fail-fast --no-ansi run`. It's worked! thank you.